# sed search/replace on macOS: Pass back reference to another command within the replace string

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed, replace

I'm on macOS and have a file with a bunch of logs and their timestamps. The timestamps have the format "seconds since Epoch", but I want to replace them all with the format "MM-DD-YY HH:MM:SS". So for example:

`1605726368.416115` seconds since the Epoch should be replaced with `11-18-20 20:06:08`. Note the seconds since Epoch timestamps are decimal values, that's just how the logs are timestamped.

I'm trying to realize this with `sed` and `date` as follows:

`sed -E -i '' -e "s/^([0-9]+)([0-9.]+)/$(date -r \1 '+%m-%d-%Y %X')/" logfile.txt`

The problem is that `date` interprets `\1` as just 1 second instead of the back reference that refers to the `([0-9]+)` capture group in the regex. I've tried a bunch of things like replacing `\1` with `$1` or `\\1`, messing around with single- and double-quotes, and installing gnu-sed from homebrew and trying it with the `/e` flag, and nothing works. So my question is basically: **Is it possible to use a \N back reference within a $(...) command substitution (specifically in the context of a sed replace string)?**

If possible, I want to avoid reading each line in a while loop and calling `sed` on each line because that is super slow.

Comment: I've just tried sed -En "s/^([0-9]+)([0-9.]+)/$(date -r \1 '+%m-%d-%Y %X')/p" <<< "1605726368.416115" and it works fine.

Comment: @Raman Unfortunately that doesn't work, the resulting date is 01-01-1970 01:00:01, which means that `date` just interpreted `\1` as 1 second.

Comment: Interesting. Shows as 08-21-2020 15:03:33 on my Centos system and so it seems like a sed version issue

Comment: The command substitution does not know what `\1` is within it so it treats it as a literal `1`, for example, `sed -E "s/^\b([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)\b/date -d @\1 '+%m-%d-%Y %X'/" < logfile` correctly formats the command without command substitution resulting in `date -d @1605810879.815366972 '+%m-%d-%Y %X'` (which can then be used to obtain the correct time). I'm looking for how to get around the command substitution issue.

Comment: Command substitution will run before `sed` replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a command substitution over a back-reference of a captured value in `sed` as command substitution will run before and it will take literal `\1` instead of the actual captured value.

If you are fine with a `perl` solution then this will work fine:

```sh
perl -pe 's/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/{
use POSIX qw( strftime ); strftime("%m-%d-%Y %X", localtime($&));
}/e' file.log
```

PS: You may use `gmtime` instead of `localtime` if your EPOCH value is in `GMT`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution outputs the result to stdout, but the file remains unchanged. I need the file to be changed in place.

Comment: Great, thanks. So is there no way around the fact that with sed, command sub will run before? I.e. a sed solution isn't possible here (or at least not feasible)?

Comment: Also, can you explain why in Raman's first comment to my question, the command substitution works fine for him (according to him)?

Comment: It won't work on OSX sed for sure due to the reason stated. May be using `/e` mode in `gnu-sed` it might be possible.

Comment: I tried gsed previously and I get a "date: illegal time format" error unfortunately. I tried the exact gsed command you suggested too just to make sure. It's looking like perl might be a better choice. I know it's probably possible with awk as well, but I have little experience with it.

Comment: No worries, I know that, I am simply waiting a little longer to see if others will answer. But your answer will likely become the accepted one ;)

Comment: I tried using `sed .../e` but this fails when you have additional data after the timestamp. The `perl` works fine.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, but it might be good to remove the gnu-sed part because it doesn't work. I keep getting a "date: illegal time format" error, even when I just write `date -r \1` and no `'+%m-%d-%Y %X'`.

Answer (score 1):

I will start with two bad solutions with `paste`, that might amuse you.

When all lines start with a timestamp, you can use

```
paste -d " " <(printf '%(%m-%d-%Y %X)T\n' $(cut -d"." -f1 logfile.txt)) \
             <(cut -d" " -f2- logfile.txt)
```

This will fail for a line with only a linestamp, for the next years you can use

```
paste -d " " <(printf '%(%m-%d-%Y %X)T\n' $(cut -d"." -f1 logfile.txt)) <(cut -c19- logfile.txt)
```

You can use `sed` almost like you did. First extract the commands and next source them.

```
. <(sed -E 's/^([0-9]+)([0-9.]+)(.*)/printf "%(%m-%d-%Y %X)T" "\1"; echo "\3"/' logfile.txt)
```

I think `awk` is best:

```
awk -F "." '{ print strftime("%m-%d-%Y %X",$1) substr($0,17) }' logfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the multiple options. I like the awk solution, though on macOS I first have to install GNU gawk since strftime is a gawk extension. I should really learn awk more, I have little xp with it. The sed solution is not working unfortunately.